# Computing Multivariate Cumulative Normal Distribution

Tags: numerical-methods

I am trying to compute the CDF of a Multivariate Cumulative Normal Distribution in the 1000th dimension (I have a 1000 vectors and their covariance matrix). I haven't been able to find a fast way to compute this, numpy and scipy all take take too long.

Are there any libraries (platform and language doesn't matter) that can compute this in a reasonable amount of time? If not, are there any numerical methods that can achieve this?

Comment: 1) Add takes like performance, numpy, scipy. 2) Give a working example what you have done (including testdata and timings)

Comment: @max9111 Those things are all irrelevant to the problem. CDF for multivariate normal distribution has asymptotic complexity that numpy and scipy implement are exponential in N. With N=1000 in my case, a single call will take decades to compute on a machine. I want to know if there are other implementations out there that can compute the CDF for N=1000 in a more reasonable time span. All major standard libraries in major numerical libraries have this problem, I don't know if there are other implementations out there that aren't exponential in N.

Comment: Try [PyMC3](https://docs.pymc.io/index.html), it uses Theon as backend